# UIView Shadow not displaying

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

I'm not sure if I'm missing something but what should be a simple task just doesn't want to work. I'm trying to add a drop shadow to a `UIView` in `iOS 6`. I'm using storyboards and auto layout. I'm drawing the `UIView` in the storyboard scene with a white background. Then linking it to an `IBOutlet`.

in my .h file I declare the `IBOutlet` and the property

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIView *_loginPanel;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *_loginPanel;

@end
```

and in my .m i `import QuartzCore`

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

`Synthesize` the property

```
@synthesize _loginPanel;
```

and do the following in my `ViewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_loginPanel.bounds];

    _loginPanel.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    _loginPanel.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _loginPanel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    _loginPanel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5.0f, -5.0f);
    _loginPanel.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0f;
    _loginPanel.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
    _loginPanel.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}
```

but i get no shadow just the white `UIView` I defined in the storyboard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: you give the outlet(Reference) to the UIView??

Comment: @spill50 your code is perfectly working.I think your custom view size is bigger than your parent view. otherwise your outlet is not connected.

Comment: @spill50 your code working fine just check you give the outlet (Referance) to the _loginPanle or not..

Comment: Try without `.shadowPath = path.CGPath;`, maybe your view is getting auto resized or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can change this line :

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_loginPanel.bounds];
```

with :

```
CGPathRef path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_loginPanel.bounds].CGPath;
```

and off course remove ".CGPath" in the shadowPath line.

Maybe you can try to make this in the viewDidAppear method to see if it's not a problem of resizing.

Comment: I moved it to the viewDidAppear method and it works. :) it must be something to do with the constraints resizing the view. Thanks all I thought I was going mad.